# use pre-defined color palette in chordDiagram

Tags: r, colors, chord-diagram

I have this palette:

```
     palette_ECOFIN<-c("#9A5EA6", "#E5C473", "#B98B50", 
                    "#61276D", "#2E368F", "#D8C5E0", "#0000FF", "#800080")
```

I tried to create enough colors (I need 29) in a chorddiagram with these lines of code:

```
     library(RColorBrewer)
     getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(29,"palette_ECOFIN"))
```

And I get this error message:

```
      Error in brewer.pal(29, "palette_ECOFIN") :palette_ECOFIN is not a 
valid palette name for brewer.pal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it goes beyond **RColorBrewer** limit, but you can use the **rainbow(29)**

Comment: Sorry to necro this post - but I do not understand where the solution should be implemented. I am having the same issue, but with 41 colors. I used rainbow(41), and attempt to pass it to the 'palette' argument of chorddiag without success.